# How to create Button_Click() Event for Bootstrap Button?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, buttonclick

Bootstrap login form is below:

```
<form class="form-vertical login-form" runat="server" action="~/Default.aspx">
    <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">User Name</label>
        <input class="m-wrap placeholder-no-fix" type="text" placeholder="UserName" name="username"/>
    <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
        <input class="m-wrap placeholder-no-fix" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn green pull-right" aria-pressed="undefined">
    Log In <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
    </button>            
</form>
```

When the button is clicked, I want to create the connection to the database. So, I need to have sth like this:

```
protected void (ButtonName)_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connStr = "Initial Catalog=LoginCheck; Data Source=MYCOMPUTER; User id=sa; password=000000;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();
    ...
}
```

But it doesn't work like ASP.NET. If I double-click on the button when I am designing, it's not taking me to code behind. Please put me in the right direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ASP.Net, you want to use Server control if you want to post back.

Most of the time, `<form>` tag is located inside Master Page, so you cannot style it easily.

Here is an example -

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="form-vertical login-form">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="UsernameLabel"
            AssociatedControlID="UserNameTextBox"
            CssClass="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">User Name
        </asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserNameTextBox"
            CssClass="m-wrap placeholder-no-fix" />

        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="PasswordLabel"
            AssociatedControlID="PasswordTextBox"
            CssClass="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password
        </asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PasswordTextBox"
            CssClass="m-wrap placeholder-no-fix" />

        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SubmitLinkButton"
            CssClass="btn btn-default pull-right" 
            OnClick="SubmitLinkButton_Click">
            Log In <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

> But it doesn't work like ASP.NET

Your code (aka "code-behind") looks like it expects ASP.Net server controls e.g. `<asp:Button runat="server" id="foo"...` so it can do a `Postback` which is the the ASP.NET "web forms" way.

Having said that, you can try

- assigning a bootstrap css class to an ASP.net server control to make it look like a bootstrap button (styling)
- keep your existing HTML above handle the normal `HTTP POST` and not deal with server controls (and deal with `request.form`)

It's your choice based on what works for you. Either way the core concept is based on standard HTTP POST (html form post, asp.net web forms "postback").

Hth...